# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: 1>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is my model.py file. When i run 'python manage.py migrat' gave me a error but i don't understand what is this .

This is my
**models.py:**

```
class Myclabusers(models.Model):
    first_name =  models.CharField('first_name', max_length=100 ,default='')
    last_name  =  models.CharField('last_name', max_length=100, default='')
    email      =  models.EmailField('user email',default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name +' '+self.last_name

class Venue(models.Model):
    name     =  models.CharField('venue name' , max_length=100)
    address  =  models.CharField('address' , max_length=500)
    zip_code =  models.CharField('zip code' , max_length=20)
    phone    =  models.CharField('phone no.' , max_length=15)
    wab      =  models.URLField('url' , max_length=100,default='http://')
    email    =  models.EmailField('email' , max_length=30)
    venue_owner = models.IntegerField('venue_owner' , blank=False, default=1)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    event_name  = models.CharField('event name' , max_length=100)
    event_date  = models.DateField('event time' )
    venue       = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manager     = models.ForeignKey(User,default=User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    attendens   = models.ManyToManyField(Myclabusers, blank=True )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name + ' at '+ self.venue.name
```

**Error page**
[image: console output containing error message]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not define "User" as default. Default must be an id in this line of your "Event" model:

```
manager = models.ForeignKey(User,default=User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```